# Multi column table in Javascript using DOM

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need to output a multi column table that reads left to right. The table image shows how it should look with just the first few toys. I have to output the table using the DOM node. I also need to generate a sequential code number in the code column. I have been racking my brain over this so any help would be appreciated.

[image: image of table]

```js
var productsArr = new Array('ToyA', 'ToyB', 'ToyC', 'ToyD', 'ToyE', 'ToyF', 'ToyG', 'ToyH');
var pricesArr = new Array(18.70, 11.95, 39.95, 49.95, 54.65, 32.10, 18.70, 11.95);

for (var i = 0; i < productsArr.length; i++) {

  document.writeln('<table border="1">');

  document.writeln('<tr>');
  document.writeln('<th>Code</th>');
  document.writeln('<th>Product</th>');
  document.writeln('<th>Price</th>');
  document.writeln('</tr>');

  document.writeln('<tr>');
  document.write("<td>Generate Number</td>" + "<td>" + productsArr[i] + "</td>" + "<td>" + pricesArr[i] + "</td>")
  document.writeln('</tr>');
  document.writeln('</table>');
}
```

Comment: Please forget that `document.write` ever existed and learn to use DOM functions like `document.createElement` and `document.addChild`. Your code is from the 90's.

Comment: thanks Barmar. The 90's were great.

Comment: @Barmar you meant `appendChild`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your id or number, this one is random...

```js
document.write(
  "<td>" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000) + "</td>" +
  "<td>" +    productsArr[i] + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + pricesArr[i] + "</td>"
);
```

This is sequential...

```js
document.write(
  "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
  "<td>" +    productsArr[i] + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + pricesArr[i] + "</td>"
);
```

Comment: Thanks Sonjz. I used the sequential solution. Works great.